# How can I check if it is the first time the application launched?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to check if my app is the first time launched ? , Can Anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fun isFirstOpen(): Boolean {
        val pref = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
        val isFirst = pref.getBoolean("key", true)
        with(pref.edit()){
            putBoolean("key", false)
            commit()
        }
        return isFirst
    }
```

Comment: If this is the first time i want to show intro screen,  else I navigate into app, how can i do it ?